# What is the difference between Upper and Lower Function when used in a Where clause?

Tags: postgresql

I understand when you type, for example:

```
SELECT * from customers
WHERE UPPER(product) like 'BANK ACCOUNT';
```

All records come back with bank account, uppercase and lowercase, but the same result set is returned when I type:

```
SELECT * from customers
WHERE lower(product) like 'bank account';
```

Thanks for help in advance!

Comment: The first one transforms all characters in the `product` column to uppercase before comparing, and the second one transforms all characters of `product` to lowercase. However the result set is not modified, because the `*` is what you are retrieving (all fields, in their original state).

Answer (score 1):

Logically speaking, both your queries are doing the same thing, namely making the `product` all uppercase/lowercase and then comparing to a literal which is all uppercase/lowercase.  Note that Postgres has a case insensitive regex like which you may use here:

```
SELECT *
FROM customers
WHERE product ~* 'bank account';
```

Or, we could use `ILIKE`:

```
SELECT *
FROM customers
WHERE product ILIKE '%bank account%';
```

Comment: @MassiveOwl Hi owl, no regex like is different from `ILIKE`, but as I'm a regex enthusiast, I gravitate towards the former.  In terms of performance, I would expect both to behave fairly similarly.  At least, they are using almost identical logic.